# Batch file for installed software

Tags: batch-file

I am very new to batch just learnt a few. I agree to having shamelessly lifted this code from a website. This is the code I want for displaying list of installed software, however there is just one problem, the version and the softwares are being displayed in different lines. How can I have both in the same line?

Ex: If you run the batch you will see the versions at the beginning and then the softwares.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
@echo off
If Exist C:\Final.txt Del C:\Final.txt
regedit /e C:\regexport.txt "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
regedit /e C:\regexport2.txt "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
regedit /e C:\regexport3.txt "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
find "DisplayName" C:\regexport.txt > C:\regprogs.txt
find "DisplayName" C:\regexport2.txt >> C:\regprogs.txt
find "DisplayName" C:\regexport3.txt >> C:\regprogs.txt
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (C:\regprogs.txt) do echo %%~a >> C:\installedprogs.txt

find "DisplayVersion" C:\regexport.txt > C:\regprogs.txt
find "DisplayVersion" C:\regexport2.txt >> C:\regprogs.txt
find "DisplayVersion" C:\regexport3.txt >> C:\regprogs.txt
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (C:\regprogs.txt) do echo %%~a >> C:\installedprogs.txt

del C:\regexport.txt
del C:\regexport2.txt
del C:\regexport3.txt
del C:\regprogs.txt
sort C:\installedprogs.txt > C:\alles.txt
del C:\installedprogs.txt


:: script om alle dubbele lijnen eruit te gooien
REM -- Prepare the Command Processor --
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL EnABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM -- Prepare the Prompt for easy debugging -- restore with prompt=$p$g
prompt=$g

rem The finished program will remove duplicates lines

:START
set "_duplicates=TRUE"

set "_infile=C:\alles.txt"
set                        "_oldstr=the"
set                                    "_newstr=and"

call :BATCHSUBSTITUTE %_infile% %_oldstr% %_newstr% 
pause
goto :SHOWINTELL
goto :eof


:BATCHSUBSTITUTE

type nul> %TEMP%.\TEMP.DAT

if "%~2"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %1|find /n /v """') do (
    set "_line=%%B"
    if defined _line (
        if "%_duplicates%"=="TRUE" (
            set "_unconverted=!_line!"
            set "_converted=!_line:"=""!"
            FIND "!_converted!" %TEMP%.\TEMP.DAT > nul
            if errorlevel==1 (
                >> %TEMP%.\TEMP.DAT echo !_unconverted!
            )
        ) 
    ) ELSE (
        echo(>> %TEMP%.\TEMP.DAT
    )
)
goto :eof


:SHOWINTELL
@echo A|move %TEMP%.\TEMP.DAT C:\allesnietdubbel.txt
del C:\alles.txt

::Alle lijnen weggooien waar 'KB' in voor komt
type C:\allesnietdubbel.txt | findstr /V KB > C:\drivers\Final.txt
goto :eof



exit
```

Comment: If you're "new to batch" then you will be best off not learning it right now - Microsoft has moved on from this 30-plus year old language and the recommended environment for scripting in Windows is now PowerShell. To find installed software, the [`Win32_Product` WMI class is what you want to look at](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/11/13/use-powershell-to-quickly-find-installed-software/), at least to get started.

Comment: Thanks alroc, I know PS is good but I am close to finding what I want which is why I am pushing for it.

- I have also read that WMI class does not show all installed softwares. Only registry entries do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next approach. **Edited** - saves output to a `csv` file [(rfc4180 compliant)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180):

```
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "_csvfile=%TEMP%\%COMPUTERNAME%_39082171.csv" change to match your needs
> "%_csvfile%" (
      rem (facultative, optional) CSV header
  echo "version","displayname","comment"
  call :getsw "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
  call :getsw "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
  call :getsw "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
)
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:getsw
for /F "delims=" %%g in ('reg query "%~1" 2^>NUL') do (
    set "_swRegKey=%%~g"
    set "_swName="
    set "_swVers="
    for /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%G in ('
      reg query "%%~g" /V DisplayName 2^>NUL ^| findstr /I "DisplayName"
                                  ') do set "_swName=%%~I" 
    for /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%G in ('
      reg query "%%~g" /V DisplayVersion 2^>NUL ^| findstr /I "DisplayVersion"
                                  ') do set "_swVers=%%~I"
    call :echosw 
) 
goto :eof

:echosw
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    if "%_swName%%_swVers%"=="" (
        rem comment up next ECHO command if you don't require such information 
        ECHO "","","unknown !_swRegKey:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE=HKLM!"
    ) else (
        echo "!_swVers!","!_swName!",""
    )
  ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

Sample output (largely narrowed down for demonstration here):

```
==> D:\bat\SO\39082171.bat

==> type "%TEMP%\%COMPUTERNAME%_39082171.csv"|findstr /I "comment KB unknown"
"version","displayname","comment"
"","","unknown HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Connection Manager"
"12.0.31101","Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 (KB2829760)",""
"12.0.30112","Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 (KB2932965)",""
"1","Update for  (KB2504637)",""

==>
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (helpful particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G`, `%~1` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- (`2>NUL`, `2>&1`, `|` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- (`2^>NUL`, `^|` etc.) [Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

Comment: Awesome, you sir are a genius.

Comment: I just have one question and I am good to go. I need to save this as an output in a csv file.

I tried this but well, my beginner status didn't help      
chdir > C:\drivers:\%COMPUTERNAME%.csv.

The idea is to save the output to a csv file with the computername.

And thanks for the links. I will read through and learn a bit.

Comment: @SiddharthSheshadri answer updated. If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.

Comment: Thank you, yes this is awesome.